# Cant send Data in AJAX call by using post method

Tags: javascript, php

here is my code, its pretty simple and works perfect:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var name='KillerSeba';
r.open("GET","../Serve/servepage.php?name="+name,true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
  alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
};
r.send();
```

This code just sends alert "Success: KillerSeba" when page loads. And my php file which answers request looks kinda of:

```
<?php
$s=$_REQUEST['name'];
echo $s;
?>
```

Then i want to use POST method instead of GET one. In order to do this, I change "GET" to "POST", changing url to php file, then add name variable to send() function, so my javascript code look like this:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var name='KillerSeba';
r.open("POST","../Serve/servepage.php",true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
  alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
};
r.send(name);
```

But now script doesnt send any Data to php file, cuz i getting only "Success:" alert. KillerSeba dissipates to somewhere. I tried to use 'name' and "name" instead of name inside of send() function, i tried to replace $_REQUEST by $_POST, but it still doesnt help. So my Queistion is: How to send Data in AJAX Request using POST method? How does this send() function work?
P.S. I prefer to use Vanilla JS Framework only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're sending the name as string without any paramerter name that's why it is not working for you with `POST` method but when you're sending with `GET` you're concatenating that name with the url. Now, you've to pass the **params** the same way you sent with **GET** method. Just try like this way, I just wrap the name to a variable called `params` that contains the `params = 'name='+name;` so you've to send it with your `r.send(params)`. See the examples here both for [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_GET) and [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST)

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var name='KillerSeba';
r.open("POST","../Serve/servepage.php",true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
  alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
};
params = 'name='+name;
r.send(params);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its working properly, but only since i added r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); to code. Header had to be sent, too; It doesnt work without it

Comment: Yeah you've to add that `Content-Type` header, I just missed out to add it on my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `name` but without any variable name (it's considered as variable name without any value).

Change your `r.send(name);` to `r.send('name=' + name);`.

For more information, take a look at the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST)

EDIT: Thanks for your hint, of course you need to set a proper header before sending the request:

```
r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: Thanks for documentation, ive read the Header needs to be sent when using POST method. And variable values, ofc