# problem bulding a public chatroom using Javascript,AJAX,PHP,MySql

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

so i am trying to create a public chat application using AJAX. the way i want it to work is: the user types something in the text area and clicks on 'send' button, AJAX will post this message to a php file which then saves that message in the database.on the same page there is also a GET request which brings messages,organized by another PHP script and writes them in  the "screen" div.i have been working on this for a week, all the ajax tutorials i found have two problems:

1:they use jQuery, i am learning Javascript and don't want to learn jQuery yet, so my code is in pure JS, also i don't want to import the entire library just for it's AJAX classes
2:they only explain how to do simple GET/POST request to a static URL or txt file while i need stuff to refresh without reloading since it's a chat room.

so after days after days of bashing my head against the wall, i have reached the conclusion that asking my question here is the only solution. i have added as many comments as i could, i have also included PHP,JS,HTML codes separately here. i have exactly 3 questions:

1:how can i refresh a div every 5 seconds,i know how to do this with jQuery but again i need vanilla JS.
i tried changing line 24 to 29 like this: http.onload = setInterval(function(){...},5000); but although the div does get refreshed the only message i see is "undefined" and i don't know what is causing this.
2:my POST request to send the message which is within a function within a Javascript click eventlistener doesn't work, i click on send button, nothing happens in the network tab of the dev tools i see the get.php response normally which belongs to the GET request but no POST request.
3: is the architecture of my chatroom ok or do you suggest a better,more efficient one?
THANK YOU!
 this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <title>Chat</title>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="logout.php">log out</a>
    <!-- this is the div i want the messages from the other users to be displayed in-->
    <div id="screen">
    </div>

     <!-- this is the text area where the user will type their message -->
        <form method="POST">
        <textarea name="room" id="room" cols="100" rows="10">
        </textarea>
     <!-- this is the send button-->
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">
      </form>
```

this is my JS:

```
<script>
     // show old messages from the user & other users
     var old = new XMLHttpRequest();
     old.open("GET" , "get.php" , true);
     old.onload = function display()
     {
       var screen = document.getElementById('screen');
       // im using inner html so i can edit the message's font/color etc in php
       screen.innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
     old.send();
       // bind the value of the text area to a variable
    var data = document.getElementById("room").value;
    var send = document.getElementById('send');
    //  i want the message to be sent only fter the button is pressed
    send.addEventListener("click" , send);
    function send() {


    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST" , "chat.php" , true);
    // perhaps the problem is that i am choosing a wrong header here?
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onload = function()
    {
      if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
      {   
          console.log('ok');
      }
    }
    http.send({message: data});
}



</script>
```

if you guys need my PHP i can send my two PHP files too(get.php and chat.php).

Comment: As an experienced webdev, I would strongly recommend bringing in jQuery even just for those AJAX calls, it really isn't much to learn and will save you some headache. By not using it for a few simple things, you're going to be focusing on the minutia of web development which isn't really helpful to you right now when you're trying to just put together a quick chat room and learn a few other concepts.

Comment: thank you i am building these projects to learn since it"s a hobby of mine so i don"t mind if building them takes time if i ever work for a company i will for sure  use the fastest way but right now im learning javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate and actually encourage your quest for vanilla Javascript, and since I see you want to learn, I won't give you all the code here.

1. The `send` function is not working because you have a conflict of
   variables. Your `var send = document.getElementById('send');` and
   your function `send`. Since you are learning, I would also suggest to have more meaningful and less generic names. This is also to prevent future clash of variables/functions or reserved keywords especially if coding in a team. Instead of `get`, `send`, `get.php`, etc.. try `sendchatmessage()`, `getallmessages()` in camelCase or however_you_like_best.
2. Your whole chunk of `old` get request code should really be wrapped in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){..});` This is because you are calling on dom objects `room` and `send` and you have no idea if they are ready yet.
3. The `setInterval` should work, but I will leave it to you to find out exactly how to use it. Some hints. It returns an id to the timer which you should store and clear when needed. You can refactor your `get old` code into a function so that you can use it in `setInterval` to be called repeatedly. 
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
4. This is not the best architecture as you are polling the server constantly and at a low rate. So a user sending a message might see his/her own message only 5 seconds later. Also it is a strain on resources if the chat is not used constantly and it polls for nothing. It also seems like you are not adding on to the div, but returning the whole history (I am guessing from the structure of your code), which means the data overhead will get larger and larger. You can explore into Web Sockets as a solution to this polling problem. Alternatively, you can think of ways to minimize this issue, eg. adding the user sent message directly into the `screen` immediately, returning an id along with only new messages such that you can use javascript to keep track of the order and duplicates and thus reducing the data load.

Hope this helps! Have fun and good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for your help!i was plannig on learning web sockets after this project xD

Comment: also i got another problem, u see i did change the element name and function name, but even now when i click on the send button, chat.php appears for a mili second on the network tab then disappears, and i get no console.log(), what do u think is the problem? EDIT: the problem was that i was using POST form which refreshed the page before AJAX was complete, changing the button from submit to a normal button solved the problem :D

Comment: Glad you figured it out by yourself! Have fun!

Comment: i've got one last question, i hope u can answer me xD u see the last problem i have is that i don't know how to properly send the data.in all the tuts i can find, people always send hard coded info, i am trying to send a variable though, so in my code i have var data = document.getElementById("room").value; and i have to somehow put it in my http.send() in such a way thath i will have some form of a key,value pair in my php so i can access it using $_POST['key']. i tried creating an object,stringify it and send to no avail, also i dont know how to pass a variable in form data xD

Comment: You should start a new question as this one is on a different topic and everyone will be able to help you better with some code examples. However, this would be a duplicate question as there are many examples on stack overflow. You can check out this one and tweak it to your own use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676972/cant-send-data-in-ajax-call-by-using-post-method For multiple parameters, separate with &

Comment: thank you. you can't believe why it wasn't working, i was trying to use PHP concatenation syntax "." instead of js '+=' reading the answer to the question u sent me made me realize that thank you!